# Is it compulsary to activate publishing feature to get the Welcome Page option in site settings?

Tags: publishing, welcome-page

We are using a team site template and notice that under site settings we donot get a link for setting the 'Welcome Page'. I have read that this is part of publishing feature.

I would like to know if there is any workaround for this. Also, whether the site feature or site collection feature needs to be activated and whether I need to inform the SP admin (if complications may arise after activating them or is it safe and wont have any adverse effects on the site?)?

Please guide if you have come across this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly append `_layouts/15/AreaWelcomePage.aspx` in case of SP 2013 or `_layouts/AreaWelcomePage.aspx` in case of SP 2010 or 2007 to the url and change the welcome page instead of activating the publishing feature.